# Display message in a toastr from controller in Spring

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp

I am using a toast to display the success message on my jsp page and I would like to ask if there is a way to actually display the userName which is set in a session in my controller in the toast along with the success message. 
 This is my toast :-

```
toastr.success('Successfully', 'Registered',{timeOut:2000});
```

My controller has the following line of code to set the userName:-
    `session.setAttribute("userName",userName);`

where userName has fullName as its attribute.

Comment: instead of putting the message in the session, why don't you refactor your code, make a normal ajax request and return json string through the response ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should put message to Model or ModelAndView, such as

```
model.put("message","ok");
```

Then you can use $ to display message value in Jsp.

```
toastr.success('${message}', 'Registered',{timeOut:2000});
```

Comment: You mean if I do model.put("name",userName) and inside toast I should do toastr.success('${name.fullName}', 'Registered',{timeOut:2000});

Comment: Yes toastr is in jsp... I will try this